# HTML data tables in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Message` model which has a create date. How can I make it so that I can display the date horizontally and the other attributes vertically.

So it would be something like this:

```
Date         1/1/11           2/1/11            3/1/11
Message      message1         message2          message3
Attr 1       attr1 val        ....              ...
Attr 2       attr2 val        ....              ......
```

Is there a plugin/gem that I could use in Rails, or I have to use some JavaScript library to do that?

Comment: It is just about HTML layout. You don't need Javascript here and you don't need any gems here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your controller prepare data

```
@messages = Message.select(:created_at, :message, :attr1, :attr2 ...)
@turned_messages = @messages.all.inject({}){ |h, c| c.attributes.each{ |k,v| h[k] ||= []; h[k] << v }; h }
```

Then in views:

```
<table>
  <% @turned_messages.each do |k, values| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= k %></td>
      <% values.each do |v| %>
        <td><%= v %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: That displays all the attributes in 1 line. Output looks like: attr1 attr1value attr2 attr2value. If I have multiple, it just puts everything in 1 line. I modified how I get @messages. This is what I have:  @messages = Message.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id) and I removed all in fron of inject. Could that be why my output messes up?

Comment: Actually it displays like: Message val1 val2 Attr1 attrval1 attrval2 Attr2 attrval2 attrval3....all in same line