# How to rotate by 90° an Array with ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have got

```
@my_objects = [ #<MyObject id: 1, title: "Blah1">,
                #<MyObject id: 2, title: "Blah2">,
                #<MyObject id: 3, title: "Blah3">,
                #<MyObject id: 4, title: "Blah4"> ]
```

I need to turn it into:

```
@my_objects = { :id => [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
                :title => [ "Blah1" ... ] }
```

Is there built in method or some standart approach?

I can imagine only this

```
@my_objects.inject({}){ |h, c| c.attributes.each{ |k,v| h[k] ||= []; h[k] << v }; h }
```

*This question was born while I was thinking on [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939264/html-data-tables-in-rails-3)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use *Enumerable#map* (something like `@o.map { |e| [e.id, e.title] }`) to get the ActiveRecord array into a simplified pure Ruby object that looks like this:

```
a = [[1, "Blah1"], [2, "Blah2"], [3, "Blah3"], [4, "Blah4"]]
```

Then:

```
a.transpose.zip([:id, :title]).inject({}) { |m, (v,k)| m[k] = v; m }
```

***Alternate solution:***  It might be less tricky and easier to read if *instead* you just did something prosaic like:

```
i, t = a.transpose
{ :id => i, :title => t }
```

*Either way you get:*

```
 => {:title=>["Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3", "Blah4"], :id=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

***Update:*** [Tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) has a refinement that's worth citing:

```
Hash[[:id, :title].zip(a.transpose)]
```

Comment: Thanks, DigitalRoss! `transpose` is actually what I was thinking of but for ActiveRecord.

Comment: When the attributes are the same for all the objects this is a compact approach. I'd write this, though: Hash[[:id, :title].zip(a.transpose)]

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track there, there's no custom method for this sort of pivot, and it should work, but remember that ActiveRecord attribute keys are strings:

```
@my_objects.inject({ }) { |h, c| c.attributes.each { |k,v| (h[k.to_sym] ||= [ ]) << v }; h }
```

You can use the `(x ||= [ ]) << y` pattern to simplify that a bit if you're not too concerned with it being super readable to a novice.

Comment: Thanks, tadman! I am familiar with `(x ||= [ ]) << y` trick, also we can initialize our hash with empty arrays to get rid of this at all

Comment: Watch out when you create your default empty array hash, as if you get it wrong all the elements of the hash will inadvertently be the same array instance. The short version that works is: `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }`

Comment: I know that. That's why I don't use it :).

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach (no eachs!):

```
pairs = @my_objects.map { |obj| obj.attributes.to_a }.flatten(1)   
Hash[pairs.group_by(&:first).map { |k, vs| [k, vs.map(&:second)] }]
#=> {:title=>["Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3", "Blah4"], :id=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

As usual, [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html) allows to write nicer code; in this case `Enumerable#map_by` would avoid using the ugly and convoluted pattern `group_by`+`map`+`map`:

```
@my_objects.map { |obj| obj.attributes.to_a }.flatten(1).map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }   
#=> {:title=>["Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3", "Blah4"], :id=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```